# Blank popup in leaflet R

Tags: r, maps, leaflet, r-leaflet

I am trying to map San Francisco's crimes in a map. The below code intends to map every crime (lat, lng) and when the marker is clicked, show the "category" column of the dataset. 
Right now the below code shows a blank text box when I click the marker.
Can anybody help?

```
    sf <- read.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/uwescience/datasci_course_materials/master/assignment6/sanfrancisco_incidents_summer_2014.csv")
crime <- data.frame(lat = c(sf$Y),
                      lng = c(sf$X))
cat <- c(sf$Category)

library(leaflet)
crime %>% 
  leaflet() %>%
  addTiles() %>%
  addMarkers(popup = paste(sf$Category), clusterOptions = markerClusterOptions())
```

Comment: The popups are working fine for me - I'm seeing the category of crime in the pop-up

Comment: @SymbolixAU, what do you think would be my problem? I have latest RStudio.

Comment: Works for me too. Using R 3.4.0, leaflet 1.1.0, latest RStudio Windows 7.

Comment: I am in R3.3.3, RStudio 1.0.136 and just re-downloaded leaflet, no success.

Comment: Latest RStudio is 1.0.143. Don't know whether that matters.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```r
sf <- read.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/uwescience/datasci_course_materials/master/assignment6/sanfrancisco_incidents_summer_2014.csv")

library(leaflet)

sf %>% 
   leaflet() %>%
   addTiles() %>%
   addMarkers(lat = ~Y, lng = ~X, popup = ~Category, clusterOptions = markerClusterOptions())
```

I'm not sure what your issue is, but using the formula syntax allows leaflet to build the list of pop-up labels on its own and does not require calling `paste` explicitly or subsetting the original dataframe.